# How can typescript generate single one javascript file without reference typescript file code

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can typescript generate single one javascript file without reference typescript file code?

Here are two typescript source files.

```
Class source1{...};

Class source 2{...};
```

Here are another two typescript files.

```
///reference path=’source1’

Class reference1{...};

///reference path=’source2’

Class reference2{...};
```

I will generate reference1 and reference2 to single one js file.
But in the js file, there are source1 and source2 code.
How can I get single javascript file without souce1 and soucre2 code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that you need to split your compilation into two phases, one to generate soruce1 and soruce2, and another one to generate reference1 and reference2. The best way to do this is to generate a .d.ts from the first batch of files then reference that in your second compilation.

to generate sources.d.ts:

```
tsc --declaration --out soruces.js soruce1.ts source2.ts
```

now your files should look like:

```
///reference path=’sources.d.ts’

Class reference1{...};

///reference path=’source.s.ts’

Class reference2{...};
```

the second compilation would be:

```
tsc --out references.js reference1.ts reference2.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the compiler to do conflicting things.

If you want a single output file, you use the flag:

```
tsc --out single.js app.ts
```

This tells the compiler to walk any dependencies, combine the output in the correct order and save it in single.js

If you don't want a single file, you leave out the flag and each TypeScript file will be paired with its output JavaScript file.

You are asking if you can combine files without including referenced files - that isn't possible.